# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)}\right)$

Tags: limits, analysis

Our purpose is to calculate
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)}\right) \tag1$$

Claim $(1)$ to be $y$.

\begin{align}
y=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\{f'[g(x)]g'(x)-f'[g(-x)](-g'(-x))\}[g(x)-g(-x)]\\
-\{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]\}[g'(x)+g'(-x)]
\end{array}\right)}{[g(x)-g(-x)]^2} \tag2\\[8pt]
=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left\{\frac{f'[g(x)]-\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)}}{g(x)-g(-x)}g'(x)+\frac{f'[g(-x)]-\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)}}{g(x)-g(-x)}g'(-x)\right\} \tag3\\[8pt]
\overset{L'Hospital}{=}&\frac{f''[g(0)]g'(0)-y}{g'(0)+g'(0)}g'(0)+\frac{-f''[g(0)]g'(0)-y}{g'(0)+g'(0)}g'(0) \tag4\\[8pt]
=&-y \tag5
\end{align}

Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)}\right)=0 \tag6$$

Is this calculation correct? Are there any ways to explain it?

Comment: Note L'Hopital's rule is only valid when the limits of the numerator and denominator are both zero or both infinity. Are you assuming $g$ is even?

Comment: to use L'Hospital's rule here $g$ need not to be $0$, because the limit is $x\rightarrow 0$, and the denominator is $0$.

Comment: If $g(x)=x$ and $f(t)=t$ then the limit is $1$.

Comment: I think you forget to take the derivative.

Comment: Right. Maybe this is true if $g$ is differentiable and $f$ is twice differentiable at $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$, as you've assumed. $g(x)=x$ and $f(t)= t \cdot |t|$ is an example where the limit exists and is not zero; $f$ is not twice differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
F(x):=\frac{f[g(x)]-f[g(-x)]}{g(x)-g(-x)} \tag{1}
$$
is an even function of $x$. Therefore, *if* $F(x)$ is differentiable *and* $F'(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}F'(x)=F'(0)=0$. Having said that, let me give a couple of examples in which the limit does not exist; in both cases, $g(x):=x$:

1. $f(x):=x^{1/3}$; then $F(x)=x^{-2/3}$ and $F'(x)=-\frac{2}{3}x^{-5/3}$ for $x\neq 0$;
2. $f(x):=x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)$; then $F(x)=x\operatorname{sgn}(x)=|x|$ and $F'(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ for $x\neq 0$.